# Recharts - Draw a trend line on top of a barchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

Hi I am creating a barchart using the Recharts library. I am wanting to draw a trend line on top of the barchart like so:
[image]

I am using the following to draw the barchart:

```
       <BarChart data={transformedDataByCategory}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" vertical={false} />
            <XAxis
              dataKey="category"
              interval={0}
              tickLine={false}
              tick={(e) => {
                const { payload: { value } } = e;
                e.fill = theme.colors.onfCategory[value].base;
                e.fontSize = '11px';
                e.fontWeight = 'bold';
                return <ChartText {...e}>{value}</ChartText>;
              }}
            />
            <YAxis />
            <Legend />
            <Tooltip cursor={{ fill: '#f1f1f1' }} />

            {years.map((year, i) => <>
              <Bar key={`year_${i}`} dataKey={year} fill={yearColours[i]}/>
            </>)}
       </BarChart>
```

I have tried using the ReferenceLine component to draw on top of the graph but have had no luck. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: how to draw smooth trend curve instead of line?